# How can I make sub-menu items open to LEFT not to right?

Tags: css

I am changing some parts of my WP site to RTL.
Everything is OK except for sub-menu items. when the cursor goes over a menu item, obviously some sub-menu item opens. Now my problem is with its direction of opening. In other words, I need sub-menu items be opened to left.

I tried a simple CSS code,

```
#nav {direction: rtl;}
```

Unfortunately this code is effective only regarding menu text direction.
Is there any CSS trick making sub-menus open to LEFT?

My domain address is http://sciself.com

Thanks

Shaqpad

Comment: We would have to see the code to give you a usable response. Could you post your html and css for the menu?

Comment: Show us the related code..

Comment: Domain address added. Could this be helpful?

Comment: @Shaqpad Please provide the **code related to the problem** allways here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `text-align: left;` to the selector:

`#wrapper #nav ul li ul li a, #wrapper #sticky-nav ul li ul li a`

FullCode:

```
#nav ul ul, #sticky-nav ul ul {
    left: auto !important;
    right: 0 !important;
}
#nav ul ul li:hover ul, #sticky-nav ul ul li:hover ul {
    right: 170px !important;
    left: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rahil. I added the code. But the problem persists. May I ask you have a look at http://sciself.com?

Comment: @Shaqpad I cannot see the changes also the style isn't applied to the selector? Where did you paste the above code?

Comment: Actually, I pasted it in Wordpress child theme style.css file. Was that wrong? Other CSS codes added there do work.

Comment: Other than adding that code, Should I do any thing else?

Comment: @Shaqpad See my edit. You just have to add `!important;` after the property value.

Comment: I did it. Texts aligned at left. But hum... I appreciate your help but I think my statement of problem was not clear. I mean, sub-menu items open over the right side of menus and this is the problem. I want this guys to go over the left side of menu as the site language will be right-to-left.

Comment: Please look the comment, Dear Rahil.

Comment: @Shaqpad are you using plugin for your submenus or its wordpress default?

Comment: Just the Avada theme itself.

Comment: I did it. The code 'right: 0 !important' works **well** except that sub-menus open exactly over parent-menus. Can you solve this, Rahil?

Comment: Done. The position of main menu relative to parent-links is **excellent**. But the sub-menus still open over right hand side.

Comment: @Shaqpad Please paste the above code it will work. It seems there are some embedded styles to index document (And its not possible to override those styles from style.css file). In avada i think there will be option box for custom css please try to paste there and let me know.

Comment: Finished. Inside Avada options page, as you said, there is a field for Custom CSS. The code you provide me were added there. It seems indifferent to this, doesn't it?

Comment: Oh! Yeah yeah, your code works perfect. And one thing more, **Thank Your for Your Favor**.

Comment: Sure! Sorry man! I totally forgot it. I did it .But my reputation is low and can not add "This answer is useful".